# How can I make raw_input tolerance more robust in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, while-loop, string-formatting

I'm new here and to programming so please take it easy.  I understand that almost anybody reading this knows more than I do and that I'm probably doing it wrong.

That being said, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
while True:
    arrival = raw_input('Arrival time? Example 8:30 \n')

    if  arrival != "%s%s:%s%s" % (range(0, 1), range(0, 10), range(0, 7), range(0, 10):

        arrival = raw_input('Follow the example: 8:30 \n)
        break

    elif arrival == "q":
        print "escape velocity reached!!!"
        return 0
```

The "if" statement doesn't have proper syntax and I don't even know if this is how one should/would go about writing this code in the first place.  Basically, I would like the user input to be in the format 1:11 or 11:11, or my code breaks.  Please ignore elif, its just there to break the loop while I'm testing.

Main question:

1. How can I fix this code or the implement the idea behind this code?

Related questions:

1. How can I get python to accept many different possible combinations of "properly" formatted strings (XX:XX or X:XX)?
2. What is a better way to coerce somebody into inputting data within a range of tolerance in a specific format or increase raw_input tolerance?
3. What is a better way to do all of the above or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance!

p.s.

1. I know that the only way to get a good answer is to ask a good question... Any tips on better question formatting appreciated as well.

Comment: Looks like you want to check/match the input with a desired format. You might want to try a regex, or perhaps use try/except with strptime() https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: @monkut Thank you.  I'll read up on that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

- Use `time.strptime` to parse the time. A format string of `'%H:%M'` works OK for
  your example, you could get more specific or try to support multiple formats
  if you need to.
- Use `try/except` to deal with input that can't be parsed properly. `strptime` will raise
  a `ValueError` if the format doesn't match, so you use `except` to deal with that
- Set the `time_ok` flag to True (and therefore exit the `while` loop) once we've got a time that can be parsed.

Code:

```
import time

time_ok = False
while not time_ok:
    arrival = raw_input('Arrival time? Example 8:30 \n')
    if arrival == 'q':
        print("Exiting.")
        break
    # Try to parse the entered time
    try:
        time_data = time.strptime(arrival, '%H:%M')
        time_ok = True
    # If the format doesn't match, print a warning
    # and go back through the while loop
    except ValueError:
        print('Follow the example: 8:30 \n')

hours, minutes = time_data.tm_hour, time_data.tm_min
print(hours, minutes)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm too new to upvote or I would have.  I should have just posted the entirety of the code. The little program is ridiculous but I wrote it with the tools I have and understand and I bet somebody like you would clean it up in 1 minute.  Ah well.

Comment: @Goostavez: You can choose to 'accept' the best answer by clicking the tick icon, it should be just below the upvote/downvote arrows on each answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right you want people to enter a time from 0:00 to 11:59.  All you have to do is something like the following

```
while True:
    arrival = raw_input("Please enter a time in the format hr:min (such as 8:30)")
    if ":" not in arrival:
        print("Please enter a time in the format hour:minute")
        continue
    else:
        arrival_list = arrival.split(":")
        if (int(arrival_list[0]) not in range(12)) or
           (int(arrival_list[1]) not in range(60)):
            print("Please enter a valid hour from 0-12 and a valid minute from 0-59")
        else: 
            break
```

This will keep your loop going until you have a properly formatted time given as an input.

From an overall, general programming point of view I think using the `time` module is probably better, but I tried to keep this to what I estimated was your skill level.

Comment: You made a very good estimation.  I used the time module for a quick minute on the website I'm using to learn python but that's it.  After finishing that course I'm looking to get into some more complex things so if you had another idea, go for it and I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use regular expressions to match the input:

```
import re

format_ok = False
while format_ok:
    arrival = raw_input('Arrival time? Example 8:30 \n')
    if re.match("\d{1,2}:\d{2}", arrival):
        #string format is OK - break the loop
        format_ok = True
```

Comment: Thanks!  After reading up on the re module (never had any experience with it) I kind of understand some implications, maybe.  Does it allow me to tell python to bypass specific "errors" in raw_input as long as specific characters are present?

Comment: Regular expressions isn't really related to `raw_input` except that raw_input returns a string, and regular expressions work exclusively with strings. Regular Expressions are a very powerful way to verify that a string has a certain format (such as the one you described)